# C++, output of one digit after the decimal

Tags: c++

I'm new in C++ and would like to get some help.
I don't understand why I'm getting an output of only one digit after the decimal on the sum below.
I have tried to solve this with no success.

```
int main()
{
    double alt, t; 
    t = 4.5;
    // function for calculating the altitude over time.
    alt = (-0.12)*pow(t, 4) +(12.0)*pow(t, 3) -(380.0)*pow(t, 2) +(4100.0)*t +220.0;
    cout << alt << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should really consider breaking that assignment up a bit. From a readability point of view it's a nightmare, and probably half the reason you can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure what you mean by breaking it up.

Comment: Perhaps one of the operators is only using one digit due to you using only one digit after all of your whole double constants?  So, either change them to have .00 (or however many places are significant) after the decimal, or take it out completely?

Comment: Well, either use brackets to denote the order of operation (BODMAS, or PODMAS for Americans), or you could even use multiple lines to split the logic down furthur.

Comment: I appreciate your effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behaviour of `cout` is to print six significant digits of floating points. You can change that with:

```
cout.precision(10);
cout << alt << endl;
```

which gives the output:

```
12019.2925
```

which seems to be the correct solution.

You should not try to set the precision to anything higher than roughly 15, because that is about the precision limit of the double type (typically). You can use the `numeric_limits<double>::digits10` from `<limits>` to make sure what precision you actually have.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought precision() is only for limiting the output. I appreciate your effort